# remove the html tag by id using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript functions , one to add items andd one to remove them . but the created (p) tag isn't removed and if I remove all items tags remain and given ids remain (selected1 , selected2 , ...etc) so how can I remove the complete tag and reset counter

```
var sum = 0;
var total = 0;
var i = 1;

function additem(name, price) {
  document.getElementById("selecteditems").innerHTML += "<p id='selected" + i + "'  >" + name;
  document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML += "<p id='p" + i + "'  >" + price;
  document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML += "<p id='B" + i + "'>" + "<button id='selected" + i + "' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeitem(" + i + " , " + price + " ) ' style='font-size: 15px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;' >Remove</button> ";
  i++;
  sum += price;
}

function removeitem(i, price) {

  document.getElementById("selected" + i).innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("p" + i).innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("B" + i).innerHTML = "";
  sum -= price;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove an element by I’d you can use the following function

```js
var removeElement = function(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

to remove it from the DOM tree, you would need to run the following JavaScript lines

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

If you’re using a JavaScript framework like jQuery, to take an element out of the DOM, you have to use the remove() method:

```
$('#myDiv').remove();
```

Comment: I tried this solution it removed the tag but when I add new item the counter ( i ) continues and not reset to 1

Comment: you can try with <input type="hidden"> when ever ur remove the tag make it hidden value 1

Answer (score 0):

try this. i have added

> var parent = document.getElementById("parentDiv");

to select parent element by id and in second function to remove child element that is inside second function. or you can give me your full code so i can work on it

```
var sum = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var i = 1;
    var parent = document.getElementById("parentDiv");

    function additem(name, price) {
      document.getElementById("selecteditems").innerHTML += "<p id='selected" + i + "'  >" + name;
      document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML += "<p id='p" + i + "'  >" + price;
      document.getElementById("removebtn").innerHTML += "<p id='B" + i + "'>" + "<button id='selected" + i + "' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='removeitem(" + i + " , " + price + " ) ' style='font-size: 15px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;' >Remove</button> ";
      i++;
      sum += price;
    }

    function removeitem() {
      var chDiv = document.getElementById("selected" + i);
      parent.removeChild(chDiv);
    }
```

Comment: the problem is my html is in django project so I can not simulate it